# Clearence constraint between two pads of the same component, how to remove this type of error

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, drc

[image]

In this Altium, the component footprint is giving a DRC error. I changed the clarity constraint parameters, but this still shows an error.

This is the same case with all the components. The error is in the pads of the same component.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please do not post pictures of text ... copy and paste the text into your question instead

Answer (score 1):

You can change that in the Clearance rules. Go to Design > Rules > Electrical > Clearance  and choose your clearance rule, then check the box "Ignore Pad to Pad clearances within a footprint" and that should ignore the violations between pads that are part of the same component.
[image]